# Should we add r_upper_arm_joint and r_forearm_joint on planning group?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow [Moveit Setup_Assistant tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start#Pre-requisites).

In doc has this picture:

[image description http://moveit.ros.org/distros/current/w/images/thumb/1/1a/Setup_assistant_pr2_right_arm_joints.png/700px-Setup_assistant_pr2_right_arm_joints.png](http://moveit.ros.org/distros/current/w/images/thumb/1/1a/Setup_assistant_pr2_right_arm_joints.png/700px-Setup_assistant_pr2_right_arm_joints.png)

But the below it also say that r_upper_arm_joint and r_forearm_joint are fixed joint and will not be used for planning or kinematics.

So, should we add these two joint on right arm planning group?

If not, when I added what problem I will met?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181948/should-we-add-r_upper_arm_joint-and-r_forearm_joint-on-planning-group?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In theory, it shouldn't cause any difference. In practice, in the past there have been issues/bugs when dealing with different group representations. When defining a group with a set of joints, it is probably best to use only the active joints, and skip the fixed joints.

The alternative is to define the group as a chain, by selecting a starting link ( say torso_lift_link) and an ending link (ex: l_wrist_roll_link), however, there have definitely been issues in the past with the kinematic chain representation, and I think the recommendation at this point in time is to use the active joint representation you are already using.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0